# BMCT proof of lower bound and decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

## Question:

If $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing and bounded below, then prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges.

## My Solution:

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$ is strictly decreasing and bounded below.

WTS: $\{a_n\}$ converges.

Define $A = \{a_n | \forall n \in \mathbb N\} \subset \mathbb R$

Therefore by completeness Axiom inf(A) exists called $inf(A) = \alpha$

WTS: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n = \alpha$ (ie) $\{a_n\}$ converges to alpha

WTS: $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N > 0$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $n \geq N$, then $|a_n - \alpha| < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary.

Choose $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_N < \alpha + \epsilon $

Suppose $n \geq N$

$$\alpha -\epsilon <   \alpha \leq a_n \leq a_N < \alpha + \epsilon$$

$$\Leftrightarrow \alpha -\epsilon < a_n < \alpha +\epsilon$$

$$\Leftrightarrow |a_n - \alpha| < \epsilon$$

were alpha is the lower bound

As wanted

is this right?

Comment: What is BMCT ? You should avoid acronyms that are not widespread.

Comment: Basic Mathematics Convicts Trump

Comment: Sorry. BMCT = bounded monotone comparison theorem. But it doesn't matter because the question just ask to prove its definition where Its already stated. (The full definition includes bounded above too, this just asked to prove the bounded below / decreasing part)